# How do I access a local variable using ARM assembly language?

Tags: arm, inline-assembly, cortex-m

I use the following piece of assembly code to enter the critical section in ARM Cortex-M4.
The question is, how can I access the local variable primeMask?

```
volatile uint8_t primaskValue;                                   
      asm(                               
          "MRS R0, PRIMASK       \n"     
          "CPSID i               \n"     
          "STRB R0,%[output]     \n"
          :[output] "=r" (primaskValue)
          );
```

Comment: STRB makes no sense with a register output; it's a store to memory.  Just tell the compiler you produce an output in R0 and let it handle storing.  (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info / [ARM inline asm: exit system call with value read from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37363860)

Answer (score 1):

The `%[output]` string in the asm code is replaced by the register used to hold the value specified by the constraint `[output] "=r" (primaskValue)` which will be a register used as the value of primaskValue afterwards.  So within the block of the asm code, that register is the location of primaskValue.

If you instead used the constraint string `"+r"`, that would be input and output (so the register would be initialized with the prior value of primaskValue as well as being used as the output value)

Since `primaskValue` had been declared as `volatile` this doesn't make a lot of sense -- it is not at all clear what (if anything) `volatile` means on a local variable.