# Problem with implementing Store-Conditional instruction using inline assembly in RISC-V

Tags: c, inline-assembly, riscv

I would like to ask a question about how to write inline assembly code for Store-Conditional instruction in RISC-V. Below is some brief background ([RISCV-ISA-Specification](https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/riscv-spec-v2.2.pdf) on page 40, section 7.2):

> SC writes a word in rs2 to the address in rs1, provided a valid reservation still exists on that address. SC writes zero to rd on success or a nonzero code on failure.

The instruction that we will be focusing on is `SC.D` - store-conditional a 64-bit value. As shown on page 106 of [RISCV-ISA-Specification](https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/riscv-spec-v2.2.pdf), the instruction format is as follows:

```
00011 | aq<1> | rl<1> | rs2<5> | rs1<5> | 011 | rd<5> | 0101111
```

In order to use inline assembly to generate the corresponding code for SC.W instruction, we need 3 registers. The register list can be found [here](https://github.com/riscv-non-isa/riscv-asm-manual/blob/master/riscv-asm.md#general-registers).

The register field of the instruction is 5 bit each. Hence, there are 32 general registers in RISC-V: x0, x1, ... x31. Each register has its own ABI(application binary interface), for instance, register `x16` corresponds to `a6` register, hence, the corresponding 5-bit value should be `10000`.

I choose the following registers assignment:

- rs2: a6 register (register x16, i.e. 0b10000)
- rs1: a7 register (register x17, i.e. 0b10001)
- rd: s4 register (register x20, i.e. 0b10100)

Hence, by filling in the corresponding register bits of the original instruction, we have the following:

```
00011 | aq<1> | rl<1> | 10000 | 10001 | 011 | 10100 | 0101111
```

For the two bits `aq` and `rl`, it is used for specifying the ordering constraints (page 40 of [RISCV-ISA-Specification](https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/riscv-spec-v2.2.pdf)):

> If both the aq and rl bits are set, the atomic
> memory operation is sequentially consistent and cannot be observed to happen before any earlier
> memory operations or after any later memory operations in the same RISC-V hart, and can only be
> observed by any other hart in the same global order of all sequentially consistent atomic memory
> operations to the same address domain.

So we just set both bits to 1 since we want `SC.D` to be executed atomically. Now we have the final instruction bits:

```
00011 | 1 | 1 | 10000 | 10001 | 011 | 10100 | 0101111

-> 00011111|00001000|10111010|00101111
     0x1f     0x08     0xba     0x2f
```

Since RISC-V uses little endian, the corresponding inline assembly can be generated by:

```
__asm__ volatile(".byte 0x2f, 0xba, 0x08, 0x1f");
```

There are also some other preparations like loading values into rs1(a7) and rs2(a6) registers. Therefore, I have the following code (but it did not work as expected):

```
/**
 * rs2: holds the value to be written. I pick a6 register.
 * rs1: holds the address to be written to. I pick a7 register.
 * rd: holds the return value of SC.D instruction. I pick s4 register.
 * 
 * @src: the value to be written. rs2. a6 register 
 * @dst: the address to be written to. rs1. a7 register 
 * @rd: the value that holds the return value of SC.D
 */
static inline void sc(void *src, void *dst, uint64_t *rd) {
    uint64_t *tmp_src = (uint64_t *)src;
    uint64_t src_val = *tmp_src; // 13
    uint64_t dst_addr = (uint64_t)dst;
    uint64_t ret = 100;

    // first of all, need to prepare the registers a6 and a7.

    /* load value to be written into register a6 */
    __asm__ volatile("ld a6, %0"::"m"(src_val));

    /* load the address to be written to into register a7 */
    __asm__ volatile("ld a7, %0"::"m"(dst_addr));

    /* the actual SC.D: */
    __asm__ volatile(".byte 0x2f, 0xba, 0x08, 0x1f");
    // __asm__ volatile("sc.d s4, a6, (a7)"); // this does not work either.
    
    /* obtain the value in register s4 */
    __asm__ volatile("sd s4, %0":"=m"(ret));
    *rd = ret;

    return;
}

int main() {
    uint64_t *src = malloc(sizeof(uint64_t));
    uint64_t *dst = malloc(sizeof(uint64_t));
    uint64_t rd = 20;

    *src = 13;
    *dst = 3;

    sc(src, dst, &rd); // write value 13 into @dst, so @dst should be 13 afterwards

    // the expected output should be "dst: 13, rd: 0"
    // What I get: "dst: 3, rd: 1"
    printf("dst: %ld, rd: %ld\n", *src, *dst, rd);

    return 0;
}
```

The result does not seem to change the `dst` value. May I know which part I am doing wrong? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, do you do a LR to create a reservation before executing the SC?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: yes, that is what I did. I am totally new to inline assembly so I might did something wrong. My thoughts is - since SC instruction requires 3 registers, we need to load corresponding values into those registers before we could execute the SC. This might be the "reservation" you mentioned in your question, but I am not sure.

Comment: Besides, when I mentioned "I pick a6, a7 and s4 registers", I am not sure if that is the correct way. Will there be registers that are previously used which may cause conflict? I guess it might be. So one possible solution (I am not sure) is by issuing a memory barrier, to make sure that all instructions have finished before entering the current instruction. However, that may cause the instruction itself to be less efficient. I would like to find a way to make my inline assembly more generic, but I am still searching for them.

Comment: If you need register values to survive between instructions, make sure all the instructions are in the same `asm` statement.  If the assembler doesn't support the instruction directly, yes the easiest thing is to hard-code some registers, and tell the compiler which ones to pick using `register  int *ptr  asm("a7")` for example, to force the compiler to pick `a7` for a `"r"(ptr)` input.  And make sure to declare a clobber on whatever reg you use as a temporary.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for docs and guides.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks a lot for your answer and the link you provided. I know there is a tag but I did not know StackOverflow has a specific tag "wiki" corresponding to various topics. That is really helpful. I would go through those and see if I could figure out the solution.

Comment: [ARM inline asm: exit system call with value read from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37363860) is the Q&A I had in mind for an example of using asm register vars.  [How can I indicate that the memory \*pointed\* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56432259) is relevant for asm statements with pointer operands you deref, when you want the pointer in a register.