# Loading a the address of a pointer into a register inline thumb assembly

Tags: c, pointers, inline-assembly, cpu-registers, thumb

I'm trying to read in the address from my c-pointer to a register using inline thumb assembly.

here's a reproducible:

```
static uint32_t volatile * volatile CurrentTaskStackPtr;
CurrentTaskStackPtr = (uint32_t *) 0x20000001;
__asm volatile("LDR R8, =%0" : : "i"(CurrentTaskStackPtr) );
```

Also, I'm trying to avoid changing the state of any 'context' registers, and that's why I use an immediate read.

I keep getting this error:

```
warning: 'asm' operand 0 probably does not match constraints
  187 |         __asm volatile("LDR R8, =%0" : : "i"(CurrentTaskStackPtr) );
```

I have tried using different constraint characters, but I'm not familiar enough with assembly to make any progress, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose I could just change the pointer to a normal variable then use assembly memory access on the register that I read its value into. I don't know how much that goes against " best practices" though.

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: Trying to do context switching

Comment: are you intentionally trying to do an unaligned access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"i"(CurrentTaskStackPtr)` is asking for the *value* of a C variable as an immediate.  That can only work if the C variable is a compile-time constant, like `uint32_t  *const  CurrentTaskStackPtr = ...`.  But your variable is `volatile` (separately from pointing to `volatile`), so even with optimization enabled, you've forbidden the compiler from doing constant-propagation through the assignment to make `"i"(0x20000001)`.

**If you want the address, take the address, `"i"(&CurrentTaskStackPtr)`.**

---

Or better, ask the compiler to have the address in R8 for you, instead of putting an `ldr` pseudo-instruction into your asm template, unless you need to control how it materializes the address or something.

```
    register void *tmp_r8 asm("r8");   // forces "r" constraints to pick R8.
    tmp_r8 = &CurrentTaskStackPtr;
    asm("..."
       : // outputs
       : "r"(tmp_r8)
       : "memory"  // presumably you're going to deref that pointer
    );
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info and [ARM inline asm: exit system call with value read from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358451/arm-inline-asm-exit-system-call-with-value-read-from-memory/37363860#37363860) for an example of how this compiles.

The GCC manual (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html) is explicit that the *only* guaranteed behaviour of an register asm local variable is picking the specified register for inline `asm` statements; it's *not* guaranteed to use that register at any other time.

See also [How can I indicate that the memory *pointed* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432259/how-can-i-indicate-that-the-memory-pointed-to-by-an-inline-asm-argument-may-be) for more about why the `"memory"` clobber is necessary.  Probably best to use that instead of dummy input/output operands; you don't want the compiler trying to optimize around a context-switch anyway.

---

> Trying to do context switching

You might have a better time writing a context-switch function as `__attribute__((naked))`, so you don't have to worry about when the compiler accesses local vars relative to the stack pointer.  Changing the stack pointer inside an `asm` statement is not officially supported.  (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#index-asm-clobbers - the clobber list shouldn't contain the stack pointer.)

Except in a `naked` function, where you're writing the entire function's asm in a Basic Asm statement, and it can't inline into any callers since it's like `__attribute__((noinline,noipa))`, or like writing it in a separate `.s` file and just defining a prototype.